# Install GimageReader in Kubuntu - my last step of getting rid of Windows

Tags: kubuntu, ocr

Hope all are doing well.
I have been Windows-free for almost two weeks now. And I am not even using Wine, to use Windows software.

Initially I  installed Ubuntu, then I shifted to Kubuntu [I like the KDE desktop environment]

There is a niggle that has compelled me to move to my windows partition from yesterday.

I was using Gscan2pdf for scanning and OCR using Tessearct. This is very important to me in terms of my studies .[ I am a medical physician]

**Gscan2pdf has stopped working in Kubuntu. I tried to use the OCR Feeder. That does the job , but not quite perfectly.**

Then visiting a popular blog, I found of Gimagereader , I downloaded the .deb package of Gimagereader from Sourcefourge and installed it at Kubuntu.

**The Gimagereader is showing alright in the applications list. But when I click the icon nothing is happening.**

I installed the .exe file of Gimagereader in Windows along with Tesseract, that seems to work fine.

Please help me in installing Gimagereader to Kubuntu, I do not want to stay in Windows for Long

Sincerely waiting for some help. Thanks in advance.

Sources :

Popular blog I was referring to - http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/gimagereader-tesseract-ocr-gui-gets.html

Gimagereader at Sourcefourge - http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimagereader/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for giving me the clue, that i can not use GTK based applications in KDE based distros.
So i started to search for KDE applications.

And wow sometimes we miss to read the most obvious pages.

> YAGF (Cuneiform/Tesseract GUI)
>   YAGF is a Qt-based GUI for Cuneiform, Tesseract, and/or XSane. Installation can be from a Debian (.deb) package from GetDeb (see these instructions as well) or by compiling from source downloaded from the original site. (Qt 4.7 or later, already part of Precise, is required on your system).>

Links - one can get the YAGF from here - i tested YAGF - it actually works perfectly - http://www.getdeb.net/software/YAGF

I have quoted from one of the resource pages of Kubuntu. - http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Kubuntu_Precise_Photos_and_Graphics

Thanks a lot again, I hope this helps others.
Thank you and regards

Answer (score 0):

gscan2pdf uses gtk libraries. gtk libraries are the libraries used by gnome and allied environments (such as unity and cinnamon) to display windows. since kde is not based on gnome, there are no gtk libraries installed. hence you can't use it. I do not know if this works but install gnome or unity desktop environment alongside kde. this must install gtk libraries and then the application should work even in kde.

Comment: Actually gtk applications can be used in KDE. the problem could some something other than that